# How to clean up SQLite and set default values?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

This is the way I was taught to build a SQLite database, butI feel like there should be and easier way. Most of my columns will always start with the same default value so is there a way to set default values when i create the table.

```
public class SQLiteTable {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_LEVEL = "level";
public static final String KEY_HEALTH = "health";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_CRIT = "crit";
public static final String KEY_CRIT_RANGE = "crit_range";
public static final String KEY_CRIT_INC = "crit_increment";
public static final String KEY_HIT_RANGE = "hit_range";
public static final String KEY_HIT_INC = "hit_increment";
public static final String KEY_CHAR_IMG = "character_image";
public static final String KEY_TOTAL_XP = "total_xp";
public static final String KEY_XP = "xp";
public static final String KEY_XP_NEEDED = "xp_needed";
public static final String KEY_COINS = "coins";
public static final String KEY_SMALL_POTS = "small_pots";
public static final String KEY_LARGE_POTS = "large_pots";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Battle For Christams";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Application Variables";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_LEVEL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_HEALTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT_RANGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT_INC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HIT_RANGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HIT_INC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CHAR_IMG + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TOTAL_XP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_XP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_XP_NEEDED + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COINS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_SMALL_POTS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LARGE_POTS + " TEXT NOT NULL)"
            );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Comment: I notice that all of those strings are used only once.  Rule of thumb:  If you're going to use it in three places, make it static final, otherwise, no sense in hardcoding it (reduces readability).

Comment: They are used in other methods in the file I only copied the ones pertaining to creating a database.

Comment: Fair enough - makes sense to use them in that context, then.

Comment: John, my databases usually have more than one or two tables, so I script the entire bit. I combine the DDL into a script (SQL statements separated by a denoter), and create one script per DB version. The script can contain `CREATE TABLE` statements, `UPDATE`s, `DELETE`s, `INSERT` statements, etc. Whatever is needed to update the database. My onUpgrade then executes the scripts needed until the DB is up to date. Works like a charm, and it makes for VERY easy upgrades and very readable code.

Comment: Isn't the SQL code? so I can code it the same way you would if it's just SQL DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **DEFAULT** clause for the columns that have default values. Can't you? For more details refer [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: I did read that and I don't think I understand it properly. If i want to set a default int i Just put the number I want instead of'" TEXT NOT NULL, "'? What do i put if i want it to be a string just '("String")'?